# mysql insert nested select from other db truncates double values

Tags: mysql, truncate

I have a table in one database, call this db x. I have another database, call it y. I want to copy data from x.some_table to y.some_table. I don't want to do an exact copy of the table, because some columns don't make sense in database b. I use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO y.some_table (a_field) SELECT a_field FROM x.some_table;
```

a_filed in both tables is defined as DOULBE(17,0). If i run this:
    USE y;
    SELECT a_field FROM x;

Then I get output with full values --no floating-point truncation. However, if after insertion using the first query I showed, I get nothing but whole numbers in y's some_table.a_field. The floating-point remainders are truncated.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the column is defined as DOUBLE(17,0) in both tables?  Doesn't that specify 17 total digits with 0 after the decimal?  If so you're select from table x should also have 0 decimal places.  If its defined differently in x say DOUBLE(17,6) and you are trying to insert it into DOUBLE(17,0) then the decimals will be truncated I believe.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the problem. Didn't think to look here because both are defined that way. Perhaps my program is confused as to what schema it is looking at. I'll check in the command line and see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing truncation .. you can make sure that you properly set the floating type ..  if you think your table definition is OK, you can create a script to test it 
for example, in PHP you could do something like -

```
$sql = "SELECT your_select_field FROM your_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $sql_ins = "INSERT INTO your_insert_table SET your_field = '".$row['your_select_field']."' ";
   $res_ins = mysql_query($sql_ins);
}
```